# SQLAlchemy: Updating a versioned parent row with new child rows orphans the old child rows

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've created a versioned table in SQLAlchemy 1.3.19 (postgresql 12.3, python 3.8.5) along the lines of what's described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/versioned_rows/versioned_rows_w_versionid.html): using temporal rows, each record in the versioned table has a primary key specified by both an `id` and a `version_id`, with the latter being incremented by `1` during each update.

The versioned class table, call it `Parent`, has a one-to-many relationship with another class table, call it `Child`, that is linked to a given parent by a foreign key specified by both `parent_id` and `parent_version_id`.

I'm having trouble with a use case where I'd like to

- create new children, and assign them to the parent (and bump the parent's `version_id`), but
- leave the old children still referenced to the old version of the parent.

Instead, the old children are being orphaned, which violates the not null requirement I have on their `parent_id` and `parent_version_id` columns. Conceptually:

```
^     desired behavior            actual behavior on session.commit() of v2
|
|     parent v2 ___child 4        parent v2 ___child 4
|               \__child 3                  \__child 3
|        
|
|     parent v1 ___child 2        parent v1    child 2 (orphaned)
|               \__child 1                     child 1 (orphaned)
```

Here's a distilled example of my code. I've disabled any `before_flush` event hooking for now to test things as manually as possible:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    create_engine,
    ForeignKeyConstraint,
    Integer,
    PrimaryKeyConstraint,
    UniqueConstraint,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    make_transient,
    relationship,
    Session,
    sessionmaker,
)


Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    version_id = Column(Integer, default=1)

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('id', 'version_id', name='_id_version_id_uc'),
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', 'version_id', name='versioned_pk'),
    )
    
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    parent_version_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["parent_id", "parent_version_id"], ["parents.id", "parents.version_id"]
        ),
    )

    parent = relationship(
        "Parent",
        back_populates="children",
        foreign_keys=[parent_id, parent_version_id],
    )


engine = create_engine("<db-url>")
SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = SessionMaker()

# create parent and v1 children, commit
parent = Parent()
child1 = Child(parent=parent)
child2 = Child(parent=parent)

session.add(parent)
session.commit()

parent.children  # correctly shows [child1, child2]

# update parent with new (v2) children, commit
make_transient(parent)
parent.version_id += 1  # parent.version_id is now 2
child3 = Child(parent=parent)
child4 = Child(parent=parent)

session.add(parent)
session.commit()
```

When I call `session.commit()` I get the following `IntegrityError` exception:

```py
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null).

[SQL: UPDATE children SET parent_id=%(parent_id)s, parent_version_id=%(parent_version_id)s WHERE children.id = %(children_id)s]
[parameters: ({'parent_id': None, 'parent_version_id': None, 'children_id': 1}, {'parent_id': None, 'parent_version_id': None, 'children_id': 2})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

I've tried being more explicit about the original `children`'s relationship to the v1 parent, e.g. with:

```py
...
make_transient(parent)

with session.no_autoflush:
    old_parent = session.query(Parent).filter_by(id=parent.id, version_id=parent.version_id).one()
        child1.parent = old_parent
        child2.parent = old_parent
        session.commit()

parent.version_id += 1
...
```

And that works through this new, intermediate `session.commit()`. But by the time I try to commit the original, updated `parent` with its new children, I get the same `IntegrityError` as above.

What is the right way to accomplish the intended behavior? Ideally, I'd also like to implement this more agnostically in something like a `before_flush` event, rather than how I'm doing it here.

Thanks!

UPDATE: If I make the reference columns in `Child` nullable

```py
parent_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True, index=True)
parent_version_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True, index=True)
```

then the following will work of course without the `IntegrityError` complaint:

```py
...
make_transient(parent)
parent.version_id += 1  # parent.version_id is now 2
child3 = Child(parent=parent)
child4 = Child(parent=parent)

session.add(parent)
session.commit()  # child1 and child2 are now orphaned, but that is allowed

# re-assign child1 and child2 to the old parent version
old_parent = session.query(Parent).filter_by(id=parent.id, version_id=parent.version_id - 1).one()
old_parent.children = [child1, child2]

session.commit()
```

This is unideal though; I would still like to implement version bumping in an event such as `before_flush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I solved this. The answer is available in the [original link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/versioned_rows/versioned_rows_w_versionid.html) I posted as reference, in a similar example.

Before running `make_transient(parent)`, we need to expire the relationship between the parent and its children, via `session.expire(parent, ['children'])`:

```py
# update parent with new (v2) children, commit
session.expire(parent, ['children'])  # expires the relationship
make_transient(parent)
parent.version_id += 1  # parent.version_id is now 2
child3 = Child(parent=parent)
child4 = Child(parent=parent)

session.add(parent)
session.commit()
```

With the above, `child1`'s and and `child2`'s reference to `parent` v1 remains intact.